IndexError: index out of range in self when training Dynamic Word Embedding Model (DWB)
I am a beginner in text mining analysis and am currently learning Dynamic Word Embedding (DWB) techniques. While running the replication codes from this Kaggle notebook, I encountered the following error during training:
IndexError: index out of range in self

I am using the United Nations General Debate dataset, available here.
Below is the code I ran:
pip install git+https://github.com/llefebure/dynamic_bernoulli_embeddings.git

import pickle

import re

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dynamic_bernoulli_embeddings.analysis import DynamicEmbeddingAnalysis
from dynamic_bernoulli_embeddings.training import train_model
from nltk import word_tokenize as nltk_word_tokenize
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

def _bad_word(word):
    if len(word) < 2:
        return True
    if any(c.isdigit() for c in word):
        return True
    if "/" in word:
        return True
    return False

def word_tokenize(text):
    text = re.sub(r"co-operation", "cooperation", text)
    text = re.sub(r"-", " ", text)
    words = [w.lower().strip("'.") for w in nltk_word_tokenize(text)]
    words = [w for w in words if not _bad_word(w)]
    return words

dataset = pd.read_csv(".../un-general-debates.csv")
dataset["bow"] = dataset.text.progress_apply(word_tokenize)
dataset["time"] = dataset.year - dataset.year.min()

dictionary = Dictionary(dataset.bow)
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=10, no_above=1.)
dictionary.compactify()
print(len(dictionary))

model, loss_history = train_model(
    dataset, dictionary.token2id, validation=0.1, num_epochs=6, k=100, notebook=True)

the full error were as follows!:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[93], line 1
----> 1 model, loss_history = train_model(
      2     dataset2, dictionary.token2id, validation=.1, num_epochs=3, k=25, notebook=True)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dynamic_bernoulli_embeddings/training.py:96, in train_model(dataset, dictionary, validation, notebook, m, num_epochs, lr, validate_after, **kwargs)
     94 if i == 0:
     95     times = torch.zeros_like(times)
---> 96 loss, L_pos, L_neg, L_prior = model(targets, times, contexts, dynamic=i > 0)
     97 loss.backward()
     98 optimizer.step()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dynamic_bernoulli_embeddings/embeddings.py:112, in DynamicBernoulliEmbeddingModel.forward(self, targets, times, contexts, validate, dynamic)
    110 contexts[context_mask] = 0
    111 contexts_summed = contexts.sum(axis=1)
--> 112 eta = (self.rho(targets_adjusted) * contexts_summed).sum(axis=1)
    114 # Loss
    115 loss, L_pos, L_neg, L_prior = None, None, None, None

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py:162, in Embedding.forward(self, input)
    161 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 162     return F.embedding(
    163         input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
    164         self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2210, in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2204     # Note [embedding_renorm set_grad_enabled]
   2205     # XXX: equivalent to
   2206     # with torch.no_grad():
   2207     #   torch.embedding_renorm_
   2208     # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2209     _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2210 return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)

IndexError: index out of range in self

What I’ve Tried:

Verified that the dataset is loaded correctly and tokenized as intended.
Checked that the Dictionary object is created properly.
Looked up similar issues related to "index out of range," but I couldn't find a solution specific to Dynamic Word Embedding (DWB).

Questions:
What causes the IndexError: index out of range in self during training?
How can I fix this issue?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Can you provide the full traceback of the error?

I have added it! thanks for your efforts
